# How to partially reduce list in scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a list of integers (representing hand values)

```
val values = List(1, 200, 3, 4, 45, 45, 7, 8)
```

And a list of indexes into this list (representing hands involved in pot)

```
val indexes = List(0, 4, 5, 7)
```

I need to filter the indexes so only those with the highest hand values remain, equal highest hand values will all be included.

In this case output would be `List(4, 5)` since both 4 and 5 has the highest hand value of 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in several steps:

```
val tuples = indexes.map(index => index -> values(index)) // mapping index - value
val maxVal = tuples.map(_._2).max // get max value
val maxIndices = tuples.filter(t => t._2 == maxVal).map(_._1) // filter & map tuples
```

For brevity I've used positional notation for tuples (`_1`, `_2`), this can of course be written using pattern matching to make it more scala-ish.

P.S.1: Thank you @Joe K for simplifying aggregation.

P.S.2: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez notices, the last line can be compressed into one `collect` method with pattern matching:

```
tuples.collect { case (i, v) if (v == maxVal) => i }
```

Comment: For a second i thought maxVal will return 200 but it returns 45 right?

Comment: Yes, `indexes` are mapped, so only those are taken into consideration

Comment: I think the second line can be simplified: `val maxVal = tuples.map(_._2).max`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you very much, I hope it's ok I added that in my answer with your name;>

Comment: Actually, that `collect` statement can be further refined: `tuples.collect{case (i,\`maxVal\`) => i}`

Answer (score 1):

```
val indexedValues = values.view.zipWithIndex
val maxValue = indexedValues.toList.filter{case (v,i) => indexes.contains(i)}.maxBy(_._1)._1
indexedValues.filter{ case (v,i) => v==maxValue }.map(_._2).toList
```

in scala REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_231).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val values = List(1, 200, 3, 4, 45, 45, 7, 8)
values: List[Int] = List(1, 200, 3, 4, 45, 45, 7, 8)

scala> val indexes = List(0, 4, 5, 7)
indexes: List[Int] = List(0, 4, 5, 7)

scala> val indexedValues = values.view.zipWithIndex
indexedValues: scala.collection.View[(Int, Int)] = View(<not computed>)

scala> val maxValue = indexedValues.toList.filter{case (v,i) => indexes.contains(i)}.maxBy(_._1)._1
maxValue: Int = 45

scala> indexedValues.filter{ case (v,i) => v==maxValue }.map(_._2).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 5)
```

Comment: **filter** + **map** === **collect** - Thus `indexedValues.collect { case (v, i)) if (v == maxValue) => i }.toList`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way to process a list in a custom way is to write a tail-recursive algorithm.

```
def filterHighestIndexes(indexes: Set[Int])(data: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Int], acc: List[Int], currentMax: Int, currentIdx: Int): List[Int] =
    remaining match {
      case x :: xs =>
        val (newAcc, newMax) = 
          if (!indexes.contains(currentIdx) || x < currentMax)
            acc -> currentMax
          else if(x == currentMax)
            (currentIdx :: acc) -> currentMax
          else
            List(currentIdx)  -> x

        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          newAcc,
          newMax,
          currentIdx + 1
        )

      case Nil =>
        acc.reverse
    }

  data match {
    case x :: xs =>
      loop(
        remaining = xs,
        acc = List(0),
        currentMax = x,
        currentIdx = 1
      )

    case Nil =>
      List.empty
  }
}
```

You can test it like

```
val values = List(1, 200, 3, 4, 45, 45, 7, 8)
val indexes = Set(0, 4, 5, 7)

filterHighestIndexes(indexes)(values)
// res: List[Int] = List(4, 5)
```

---

Note, I used a **Set** instead of a **List** for the indexes just to make the `contains` more efficient. If you can't change that, it is ok to just use the **List**.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is just as simple as this:

```
scala> indexes.groupBy(values(_)).maxBy(_._1)._2
res6: List[Int] = List(4, 5)
```